# Associating related entries to a new entry when using the API

Tags: plugin-development, relations, elementcriteriamodel

This may just be a 5PM Friday issue, but I'm scratching my head over here. I'm trying to associate a string of related entry id's represented by a variable with a new entry via the API. When I pass the variable, only the first one gets inserted into the DB. If I use the string they all get inserted. Here's the insert code:

```
 $article_countries = "1021,1047,1076,1123"; 

 $entry->getContent()->setAttributes(array(
   'article_countries' => array(
     $articleCountries
    )
 ));
```

Why is the string working where the variable isn't?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can build arrays in PHP that way and you end up passing `array(0 => '1021,1047,1076,1123')` to the param.

Not shure if passing the string is supported:

```
'article_countries' => $article_countries
```

If not you could build the array like so:

```
'article_countries' => array_map('trim', explode(',', $article_countries))
```

Comment: Thanks, your comment was helpful for getting me on the right track this AM

Answer (score 0):

Thanks carlcs, your comment & fresh eyes set me on the right track this morning.

Not real sure why I was wrapping the $article_countries var in another array...

Hopefully this will help somebody else out at 5PM on a Friday...